# How to add link to user registration inside toobar in admin joomla 3 custom component

Tags: joomla, toolbar, joomla3.0, joomla-component

Im trying to write component admin side and i need to add user creation.
Dont want to duplicate existing codes just add a link.
I know how to add a task but not a simple link to that toolbar.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting a button that opens the new user screen you can try this in your component:

```
 $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
 $bar->appendButton('Link', 'users', 'New user','index.php?option=com_users&task=user.add');
```

You will need to add this to your view.html.php file wherever you're creating your toolbar.

Is that what you need?